# How to pass for Langevin equation to Fokker-Planck equation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, non-equilibrium, stochastic-processes

What is the procedure to pass from the description of a phenomenon made by the [Langevin equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_equation):
$$
\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{v}{\tau}+\sqrt{2c}\,\eta
$$
to the corresponding description with the [Fokker-Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation)?

Comment: What beyond the linked Wikipedia article is this question about? A substitution gives you $\partial_t p = \frac{1}{\tau}\partial_v(vp) + c\partial_v^2p$

Comment: It's the substitution itself and, moreover, how to pass from a stochastic description of the $x$ and $v$ (Langevin)  to a deterministic description of the $P(x)$ and $P(v)$ (Fokker-Planck)

Comment: The substitution of your equation is just a direct drop into the formula in Wikipedia, as in my previous comment. If you want $p(x)$, you'll e.g. just write the system of equations for $dx$ and $dv$, get $p(x,v)$ as a substitution to the formula on Wikipedia and integrate over $v$. As for how to derive Fokker-Planck, that's in any standard  textbook and not really a conceptual question fitting this website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a set of equations-
$$\dot{x_i}=a_i(t,\vec{x})+\xi_i(t)$$
Coordinate  $x_i$ can be $x$, $p$ and such. I na vector form it can be rewritten as -
$$\dot{\vec{x}}=\vec{a}(t,\vec{x})+\vec{\xi}(t)$$
Fokker Planck assumes the random force is whie Gaussian noise (there exist generalizations for other cases). Moreover,the random force in most cases considered as delta correlated in time -
$$\langle \xi_i(t_1)\xi_j(t_2)\rangle=2D_i\delta_{ij}\delta(t_1-t_2)$$
The equivalent Fokker-Planck is-
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=\underbrace{\left[-\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{x}}\vec{a}+\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{x}}\overleftrightarrow{D}\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{x}}\right]}_{L_{FP}}\rho$$

Notice the reversibility of this procedure - ig you know the Fokker Planck operator you can deduce the equivalent Langevin equations.

For reference Risken's [The Fokker-Planck Equation](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540615309) is the best but [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0701242) is also quite comprehensive.