# When we should use Langevin equation and when we should use Fokker-Planck equation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

As everyone knows that we can go from Langevin equation to Fokker-Planck equation which gives the evolution of probability density function. But what I don't understand is what is exactly the main difference between them as long as they are both give the variance (which then we can for example calculate the particle's size). I can't understand the main difference and the main use why I should use this and not that and vice versa and when I should do that.

Comment: Might be useful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/213794/

Comment: So let's say particle under non-white noise should be treated with Fokker-Planck equation  but it can be also treated with langevin equation..or?